# Reach Web Api Action with ampersand in query string

Tags: asp.net-web-api, query-string, html-encode, ampersand

how can I reach my Web Api Actions with ampersand in the query string?

This works:

```
http://localhost:12345/api/MyController/MyAction?user=test&pw=abc123
```

This does not:

```
http://localhost:12345/api/MyController/MyAction?user=test&amp;pw=abc123
```

Error Message is:

```
{
  "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:12345/api/MyController/MyAction?user=test&amp;pw=abc123'.",
  "messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'MyController' that matches the request."
}
```

I thought Web API would automatically decode the query string parameters but apperently it does not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use & in the query string, you are actually escaping that ampersand so that it gets read as part of that parameter.  So the Web API method is actually only receiving one parameter, "user" that has "test&pw=abc123" in it.

Comment: That is obvious to me. The point is how can I make it work with ampersand? The URL comes in a XML File, so I have to escape it.

Comment: The HTTP spec is not going to allow you to send it this way and have it interpreted as two query string variables.  Your options are to 1) Unescape it before sending or 2) Make your API just accept "user" and then parse it in C# once it arrives.  #2 seems hacky -- #1 would make more sense. Since I'm not sure what language you are using in your code that calls the API, I don't know how to suggest how to unescape it.